# Redactor js: Tap in created table

Tags: javascript, redactor

After creating a table in the redactor widget I want to jump through the cells with typing a "tab". Is there any setting for this? I could not find anything like that in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `selectionEnd` : *Set cursor to the end of an element*

example with external call:

```
$('#redactor').redactor('selectionEnd', element);
```

Reference: http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/#h-selection